# asmx web service error to connect sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-services

I published a web service on a server and this web service is trying to connect to the sql server which is on the same server.
This is my connection string:

```
Data Source=........\sqlexpress; Initial Catalog =mybooks; User Id =......; Password =......; Integrated Security=SSPI
```

I want to connect to sql using a sql user account so I used SSPI.
I created an app pool "mypool" for the service, runs under *ApplicationPoolIdentity* built-in account.
Web service gives error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "mybooks" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user "IIS APPPOOL\mypool"
```

- Should I create sql login for IIS pool "mypool"? How can I create this login?
- If I create sql login, is there a security issue?
- Can I not login to sql using sql username and password?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using SSPI which means Integrated Security = true;

So your windows credentials will be used to authenticate to the sql-server. Not your sql-server username/password. (In your case, the user specified under application pool or web server process)

Just use sql-server username/password and do not use integrated security. Your username/password will be ignored when SSPI is used.

Hope that helps.